# Update path in location-independent installation

Tags: 11.10, installation

I am trying to install [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/installing-root-source), using a location-independent installation. 
I've come as far as step 2.

The next step is:

`Add bin/ to PATH and lib/ to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.`

I've read in other questions that I need to edit .bashrc - is that correct? 
What exactly do I need to put in there to manipulate these paths?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a *location-independent* installation, do the following:

In the directory of your application (in this case the `root` directory), open (or create) a shell script `myshell.sh` (e.g. using vim:  `vim myshell.sh`)

Insert the following lines:

```
PATH=$PATH:./bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:./lib
```

Make sure to source the file after-wards:

```
. myshell.sh
```

This has the benefit that your installation is location-independent and you may relocate the directory freely. It does come at the cost that, since your shell is not a `.bashrc` or the like, it will therefore not be executed automatically. You will have to source the shell on every re-login.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, open .bashrc with gedit. View hidden files with nautilus in your home folder by pressing `Ctrl+h`.

Then add the following at the end of the file:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/another/bin
```

Now you will see, if you put an executeable in `/path/to/another/bin`, it is runnanble from the terminal.

For example, execute the following in your terminal (i assume ~/bin is /path/to/bin):

```
$ echo "echo 'hi'" > ~/bin/testing_things
$ chmod +x ~/bin/testing_things
```

and now you can just execute

```
$ testing_things
  > hi
```

instead of

```
$ ~/bin/testing_tings
  > hi
```

So probably for the program you just have add that line to $PATH, so it can directly execute the executables.

I haven't heard of LD_LIBRARY_PATH yet, but hopefully adding

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/lib
```

in your `.bashrc` will work.

Comment: Thank you - very clear explanation with example :-) Will try this asap.

Comment: this brought me on the right track , but I asked for location-independent install (which it won't be if you use the .bashrc in the home directory and give a full path)